# Network provider not providing location updates

Tags: android

This is my code to register network provider

```
 netlocationListener = new MynetLocationListener();
                locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,interval,mttravel,
                           netlocationListener);



    /*----------Listener class to get coordinates ------------- */
        private class MynetLocationListener implements LocationListener {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {



             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "accuracy & network provider"+loc.getAccuracy(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "location changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              CharSequence time1=android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yyyy  hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date());
             .LENGTH_LONG).show();
              String date =time1.toString();

              float tsp= 0;

                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location changed : Lat: " + loc.getLatitude()
                                    + " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String longitude = Double.toString(loc.getLongitude());  
                    Log.v(TAG, longitude);
                    String latitude =Double.toString( loc.getLatitude());
                    Log.v(TAG, latitude);

                    /*----------to get City-Name from coordinates ------------- */
                    String cityName=null;                 
                    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());                  
                    List<Address>  addresses = null;  
                    try {  
                     addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);  
                     if (addresses.size() > 0)  
                     // System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());  
                     cityName=addresses.get(0).getLocality();  
                    } catch (IOException e) {                 
                     e.printStackTrace();  
                    } 
                   String accuracy=Float.toString( loc.getAccuracy());
                    String s = longitude+"\n"+latitude +"\n\nMy Currrent City is: "+cityName + "accuracy"
                            + accuracy + "speed"+loc.getSpeed();

}
```

It shows true -

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Boolean.toString(locationMangaer.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If I change provider to GPS then it works perfectly but I need to get location from network provider. I checked working with internet, wifi but still no result.

Its not even entering the onlocationchanged().

Comment: have you change NETWORK_PROVIDER to GPS_PROVIDER??

Comment: yes it will work I have checked

Comment: I think you had missed to add permission for network state.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> I have added both :) Am getting GPS so I dont think it is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For network based location, they are a lot less inaccurate than GPS, meaning you need to move the device a much larger distance to allow the signal to hook on to another network tower before
    onLocationChanged() is called. Also not all network towers provide location.

Comment: so approx only if I move some 4km then it may call onLocationChanged() is it? but it has to call onlocatinchanged() for first time atleast right?

Comment: That would depend if it could get a location update in the first place. If it could not even get one update such as on airplane mode, onLocationChanged would never be called.

Comment: @likeitlikeit what was that edit? let me know what you edited and why?

Comment: I guess this may be the problem so accepting your answer thanks for the reply b'cauze my htc explorer shows n/w provider not enabled, but my sony xperia tipo and samsung young mobiles show n/w provider enabled but doesn't get location.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're initializing the location manager. I'd guess you're not getting messages using network location because you're not moving enough to trigger an location change.  Network position is not very accurate.  I've seen network positioning be over 100ft off, and would hazard a guess that your device has a hundred foot "error radius" that you will have to move outside of to get a location update.

I've cut-n-pasted my code below, you're mileage may vary.

```
// see if this line gives you what you want
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// get location via network
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,  locationListener);

// get location via GPS
//locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Comment: I have intialized locationManger but I dint showed, thought of showing only main code. and Now it is returning false for isproviderenabled() although my internet is up